# Two definitions of Hilbert series/Hilbert function in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, hilbert-polynomial

In classical algebraic geometry, suppose $I$ is a reduced homogeneous ideal in $k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$, where $k$ is algebraically closed field, then $I$ cuts out a projective variety $X$, whose Hilbert function is defined by
\begin{equation}
\phi(m)=\text{dim}_k~ (k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]/I)_m
\end{equation}
where $()_m$ means the $m$-th homogeneous part of the quotient ring. When $m$ is large, there exists a polynomial $p_X$ such that 
\begin{equation}
\phi(m)=p_X(m)
\end{equation}
$p_X$ is the Hilbert polynomial. However in the scheme world, from section 18.6 of Ravi Vakil's book, the Hilbert function for a projective scheme $X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ is defined by
\begin{equation}
\phi(m)=h^0(X,\mathcal{O}(m))
\end{equation} 
When $m$ is large, there exists a polynomial $p_X$ such that 
\begin{equation}
\phi(m)=\chi(X,\mathcal{O}(m))=p_X(m)
\end{equation}
Are the two definitions of Hilbert functions the same? I guess there are issues with reducedness, could anyone give an overall explanation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the graded $k$-algebra $A=k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]/I$. The graded $k$-algebra surjection $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]\to A$ yields a closed $k$-immersion $j:X=\mathrm{Proj}(A)\hookrightarrow\mathbf{P}_k^n$ with image $V_+(I)$. The Hilbert function $p_X$ of $X$ relative to the closed immersion $j$ (i.e. to the very ample invertible sheaf $\mathscr{O}_X(1)=j^*(\mathscr{O}_{\mathbf{P}_k^n}(1))$ is given by $p_X(m)=\dim_k(H^0(X,\mathscr{O}_X(m)))$ for $m\gg 0$, i.e., it is the Hilbert function of the finitely generated $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$-module $\bigoplus_{m\geq 0}H^0(X,\mathscr{O}_X(m))=\bigoplus_{m\geq 0}H^0(\mathbf{P}_k^n,(j_*(\mathscr{O}_X))(m))$. There is a canonical graded $k$-algebra map $A/I\to\bigoplus_{m\geq 0}H^0(X,\mathscr{O}_X(m))$ and it is an isomorphism in sufficiently large degree (see http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AG7). Thus the Hilbert functions agree for sufficiently large $m$, so the Hilbert polynomials coincide.

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes we also want to compute $h^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(m))$ when $m$ is small, e.g. $m=1,2$, do you know how to compute it from the information of $A/I$? i. e. what is the relation between the two definitions of Hilbert function when $m$ is small?

Comment: Dear @WZ_Bosons, I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that question. But I know there are some very smart algebraic geometry experts on this site that almost certainly do know the answer, so you might consider asking it as a separate question. Best wishes!

Comment: May be the correct way to think about it is, that $\chi(\mathcal{O}_X(m))$ is a polynomial for all $m$ (where $\chi$ stands for the alternating sum of $h^i$). For large $m$, the higher $h^i=0$, giving you what you want. You can immediately see the difficulties for small $m$, since the higher cohomologies play a role.